# How to select and add action to html element with Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a HTML like below and I want to add an onclick event to button element.

```
<div>
....
<button class="test"></button>
....
</div>
```

This button is genereated from JS and First I need to select this element and then I need to add an onclick event.

I tried some code but it gives below error.

```
var customButton = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var buttonElement = angular.element(customButton);
```

Error;

```
component.ts(23,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'angular'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a directive for this and when you create the element add the directive to that.

Here's one directive for click

```
import { Directive ,Output ,EventEmitter ,HostListener} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[test]',
})
export class TestDirective {
  @Output() test: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) 
  onClick(e) {
    alert('Directive Triggered!!');
  }
}
```

And you'll get every click event in the host listerner like this

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(event: Event) {}
```

Comment: Click event is not triggering. There is no console error also.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the click event this way

```
  constructor(private el: ElementRef){
  }
  const customButton: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(`#test`);

  somefunc(){

  }
  customButton.click = somefunc;
```